# Setting 'this' in React with Inverse Data Flow

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, this

I wondered if you could help me on this problem if possible? I have a `PostMain` component which passes a function down into the child component `PostForm`. On the AJAX success function of the callback I pass in the returned object and call `this.props.addPost(data.title)` function.

I am wonderding how you can set the context of `this` on the function? I then call `this.setState` in the parent component but `setState` is not defined because I haven't set the context of `this`. Please see code below: Thank you in advance.

This is the parent `PostMain` component:

```
 addPost(post) {
    this.setState({posts: post.title})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Main form</h1>
        <PostForm addPost={this.addPost} posts={this.state.posts} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This is the child `PostForm` component:

```
addPost() {
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: '/posts',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: {
           title: this.state.itemPost
         },
     success: function(data) {
        const postTitle = data.title;
        this.props.addPost(postTitle);
     }.bind(this)
    });
  }
```

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208698/react-js-prop-undefined-after-refactoring-to-es6/37213422#37213422)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just bind the function to your component before you pass it to your child.

```
<PostForm addPost={this.addPost} posts={this.state.posts} />
```

should be

```
<PostForm addPost={this.addPost.bind(this)} posts={this.state.posts} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to set the state inline in onClick:

```html
 
    <PostForm addPost={this.addPost} posts={()=> this.setState({posts: post.title})} />
```

Answer (score -1):

You should bind it in the component as well

```
  addPost ={ this.addPost.bind(this)}
```